# Cleanup Body_Class

Tags: headers

Currently, when I use `body_class()` it generates a bunch of crap that I don't need. What I'd like to do is have the following:

```
homepage: class='blog page-home'
single:   class='blog page-single'
author:   class='blog page-author'
category  class='blog page-category'
```

Should I even use an add_filter for body_class? Or just create my own function?

Comment: Theme and Plugins may rely on that "bunch of crap that [you] don't need". Is there any particular reason that extra CSS classes are such a bother?

Comment: I'm not using that many plugins and the site is really simple. I just don't want to clutter up my html with things I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the body class filter to add, edit, remove classes from the body class. Here's what the function will look like:

```
function edit_body_classes($classes) {
    // Add conditionals here...

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'edit_body_classes');
```

Looks like there's plenty of [Documentation in The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)